# How to get the first column of a pandas DataFrame as a Series?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, series

I tried:

```
x=pandas.DataFrame(...)
s = x.take([0], axis=1)
```

And `s` gets a DataFrame, not a Series.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y' : [4, 5, 6, 7]})
>>> df
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7
>>> s = df.ix[:,0]
>>> type(s)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>>
```

===========================================================================

**UPDATE**

If you're reading this after June 2017, `ix` has been deprecated in pandas 0.20.2, so don't use it. Use `loc` or `iloc` instead. See comments and other answers to this question.

Comment: How can I get column 'y' as a Series and column 'x' as its index?

Comment: `df.set_index('x').y`

Comment: Would be worth adding the .iloc alternative (as proposed by Jeff further down on this page), as it is not ambiguous in the presence of columns with numbers for names.

Comment: The answer was given in 2013; as far as I remember, `.iloc` wasn't there yet back then. In 2016, the correct answer is Jeff's (after all he's `pandas` God, mind you ;-)). I'm not sure what's SO's policy regarding update of answers due to API change; I'm honestly surprised by the number of votes for this answer, didn't think it was that useful to people...

Comment: Another note: `ix` was [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in version 0.20.

Comment: `ix` should not be used anymore, use `iloc` instead: `s = df.ix[:,0]`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/3388962) for a comparison of `iloc` and `ix`.

Comment: Wouldn't an update that actually says what the update IS be better than just telling people to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 156):

From v0.11+, ... use `df.iloc`.

```
In [7]: df.iloc[:,0]
Out[7]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is the most compatible version with the new releases and also with the old ones. And probably the most efficient since the dev team is officially promoting this approach.

Answer (score 124):

You can get the first column as a Series by following code:

```
x[x.columns[0]]
```

Comment: how can i get the last column like that?

Comment: The others work fine as well, but this one seems more intuitive.

Comment: This is no good if you have multiple columns with the same name. Whether column names should be unique or not is a separate discussion.

Comment: @Polly `x[x.columns[x.columns.size-1]]`

Answer (score 13):

Isn't this the simplest way?

By column name:

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y' : [4, 5, 6, 7]})
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
    x   y
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
3   4   7

In [23]: df.x
Out[23]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: x, dtype: int64

In [24]: type(df.x)
Out[24]:
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: In this particular case you know the name of the first column ("x"), but what the question meant was: "How can I access the first column, REGARDLESS of it's name". Also, accessing columns like this (`df.x`) is not generic -- what if the column name contains spaces? What if the name of the column coincides with `DataFrame`-s attribute name? It's more general to access columns using `__getitem__` (i.e. like so: `df["x"]`).

Comment: Also doesn't work if the column's header has e.g. spaces in it.

Answer (score 4):

This works great when you want to load a series from a csv file

```
x = pd.read_csv('x.csv', index_col=False, names=['x'],header=None).iloc[:,0]
print(type(x))
print(x.head(10))


<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    110.96
1    119.40
2    135.89
3    152.32
4    192.91
5    177.20
6    181.16
7    177.30
8    200.13
9    235.41
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df[df.columns[i]]
```

where `i` is the position/number of the column(starting from **0**).

So, `i = 0` is for the first column.

You can also get the last column using `i = -1`