# Python Rearrange The Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframe:

```
    A         Min Thresh   Max Thresh
    0          1          
    0                          10
    15.5       1               11
    13.3                       15
    10         0               15
```

Desired output:

> A 
>      1 
>      0 
>      11 
>      13.3 
>      10

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: Can you share the log behind those numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first column of a pandas DataFrame as a Series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360925/how-to-get-the-first-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-series)

Comment: Can you explain your logic here?

Comment: @Erfan He meant that if the value in column 'A' is below the value in column 'Min Thresh' then is should recieve the value of 'Min Thresh', and the same for 'Max Thresh'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['A'] = df[['A', 'MinThresh']].max(axis=1)
df['A'] = df[['A', 'MaxThresh']].min(axis=1)
```

It ignores `np.nan`, as you need.