# How to select certain columns and rows based on keyword in column1?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract/select the bottom two areas (blues) based on the values in column1.

The data is in a CSV file.

```
Case1
Not Started: 12 Sent: 3 Completed: 3

Division  Community         ResidentName   Date        DocumentStatus  Last Update
          Test Station      Jane Doe       9/6/2023    Completed       9/4/2023
          Test Station 2    John Doe       9/6/2023    Completed       9/4/2023
          Alibaba Fizgerald Super Man      9/6/2023    Not Started  
          Iceland Kingdom   Super Woman    9/6/2023    Not Started 
    
,,,,,

Case2  
Not Started: 6  Sent: 0 Completed: 2    
Division  Community         Resident Name   Date         DocumentStatus   Last Update
          Station Kingdom   Pretty Woman    9/6/2023     Not Started  
          My Goodness       Ugly Man        5/24/2023    Not Started
          Landmark Cinema   Nice Guys       5/25/2023    Not Started 
          Iceland Kingdom   Mr. Heroshi     1/24/2023    Not Started 
          More Kingdom      King Kong 

,,,,

Case3  
Not Started: 8  Sent: 2 Completed: 3    
Division  Community         Resident Name   Date         DocumentStatus   Last Update
          Station Kingdom1  Pretty Woman2   1/6/2023     Completed  
          My Goodness1      Ugly Man1       4/24/2023    Completed  
          Landmark2         Nice Guys       9/25/2023    Not Started 
          Iceland Kingdom2  Mr. Heroshi2    2/24/2023    Not Started 
          More Kingdom 2    King Kong
```

I am trying to possibly use the Pandas library if it is easier.

[image]

So, the logic is:

**Case1**:

1. Find the row that has data where column1 = '**Case1**'
2. Go down 3 rows, go right 1 column.
3. Take all the data of 5 columns until it hits a row that has no data.

**Case2**:

1. Find the row that has data where column1 = '**Case2**'
2. Go down 3 rows, go right 1 column.
3. Take all the data of 5 columns until it hits a row that has no data.

There is **Case3** on the bottom of **Case2**, but I only need to include **Case1** and **Case2**.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: @Nick Sorry. Let me try to come up with a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the indices of the rows where `column1` starts with 'Case' and write them to a list:

```
df.index[df['column1'].str.startswith('Case')].tolist()
```

Then it is just a matter of using these row numbers to extract the data of interest. You may do that using `iloc`.

Comment: Thank you. Regards to 'column1', there is no such a column with a name of 'column1'. I was referring to 1st column in the csv file. How do I express that?

Comment: If your columns are not labelled, then you may use `iloc` to get columns by position: `df.iloc[:,0]`. Check out this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364468/6440589

Comment: Are you referring to this?   df.index[df.iloc[:,0].str.startswith('Case1')].tolist()

Comment: I am getting this error: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: You may use `[df.iloc[:,0].str[:4] =='Case']` instead.

Comment: Can you please give me the example in the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
import re
from io import StringIO

def read_block(names, igidx=True):
    with open("file.csv") as f:
        pat = r"(\w+),+$\n+(.+?)(?=\n\w+,+\n$|\Z)"
        return pd.concat([
            pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
                .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                    pat, f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S) if m.group(1) in names # optional
        ], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)

df = read_block(names=["Case2"]) # you can also pass a list of block names
```

> Demo : [[*Regex*](https://regex101.com/r/gtyt3b/2)]

Alternatively, with a pure pandas :

```
def read_block(names):
    tmp = pd.read_csv("file.txt", header=None, skipinitialspace=True)
    return (
        tmp.loc[tmp[0].ffill().isin(names), 1:]
            .dropna(how="all").set_axis(tmp.iloc[1, 1:].tolist(), axis=1)
            .iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True) # this is optional
    )
```

Output :

|  | Community | Resident Name | Date | DocumentStatus | Last Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Station Kingdom | Pretty Woman | 9/6/2023 | Not Started | nan |
| 1 | My Goodness | Ugly Man | 5/24/2023 | Not Started | nan |
| 2 | Landmark Cinema | Nice Guys | 5/25/2023 | Not Started | nan |
| 3 | Iceland Kingdom | Mr. Heroshi | 1/24/2023 | Not Started | nan |
| 4 | More Kingdom | King Kong | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: **NB**: In case there is more than one block for the same *title/case*, they will be concatenated.

Comment: I modified the example of data frame on the top. Please note that there is Case3 on the bottom of Case2 which I do not want to include. I am trying to include only Case1 & Case2. How do we this? Also, how do I define pd? Do I use pandas for the 1st code (like "import pandas as pd")? I also have a question about your second code, but I will do it after I get your feedback on these two questions.

Comment: I would like to follow up on my question. I guess, first issue is how to extract only 1st two Cases (excluding third one). Thanks.

Comment: I tried with your code. The pandas code did not work, but Regex code worked. Also, I have Case3 which I do not want to include on the population. How do I go about doing (only include Case1 and Case2) it?