# How to extract certain blocks of data from a csv file using values in the first column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to extract only data in the two sections ("Admissions" and "Readmissions") starting from 3rd line & 2nd column from a **key word** in the 1st column.

Please see bottom for sample of dataset in a csv file.

```
Admissions
Not Started:12  Sent:3            Completed:3

Division        Community         ResidentName   Date        DocumentStatus  Last Update
                Test Station      Jane Doe       9/12/2023   Sent            9/12/2023
                Test Station 2    John Doe       9/12/2023   Not Started       
                Alibaba Fizgerald Super Man      9/12/2023   Not Started  
                Iceland Kingdom   Super Woman    9/12/2023   Not Started
```

,,,,,

```
Readmissions  
Not Started:1   Sent:0            Completed:1 

Division        Community         Resident Name   Date         DocumentStatus  Last Update
                Station Kingdom   Pretty Woman    9/12/2023    Not Started  
                My Goodness       Ugly Man        7/21/2023    Completed       7/26/2023
```

,,,,

```
Discharge 

Division        Community         Resident Name   Date            
                Station Kingdom1  Pretty Woman2   8/22/2023      
                My Goodness1      Ugly Man1       4/8/2023     
                Landmark2         Nice Guys       9/12/2023     
                Iceland Kingdom2  Mr. Heroshi2    7/14/2023    
                More Kingdom 2    King Kong       8/31/2023
```

So, the logic is:

Find the row that has data where column1 = **'Admissions'** or **'Readmissions'**.

Go down 3 rows, go right 1 column.
Take all the data of 5 columns until it hits a row that has no data.

So, I would like to get the blue box section as an output for each:

This is an illustration:
[image]

I got this code from [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100877/how-to-select-certain-columns-and-rows-based-on-keyword-in-column1), but I was not able to get it resolved / get solutions for few weeks, so I am posting this fresh.

```
import re 
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def read_block(names, igidx=True):
    with open("Test1.csv") as f:
        pat = r"(\w+),+$\n+(.+?)(?=\n\w+,+\n$|\Z)"
        return pd.concat([
            pd.read_csv(StringIO(m.group(2)), skipinitialspace=True)
                .iloc[:, 1:].dropna(how="all") for m in re.finditer(
                    pat, f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S) if m.group(1) in names # optional
        ], keys=names, ignore_index=igidx)

df = read_block(names=["Admissions"])    
print(df)
```

Bottom is current output, but it concatenated all three sections.

I would like to have a separate output using a keyword ("**Admissions**",  "**Readmissions**") in the 1st column as a variable in the code.

```
          Sent: 3    Completed: 3 Unnamed: 3       Unnamed: 4   Unnamed: 5
0           Community   Resident Name       Date  Document Status  Last Update
1        Test Station       Jane Doe   9/12/2023             Sent    9/12/2023
2      Test Station 2        John Doe  9/12/2023      Not Started          NaN
3   Alibaba Fizgerald       Super Man  9/12/2023      Not Started          NaN
4     Iceland Kingdom     Super Woman  9/12/2023      Not Started          NaN
5             Sent: 0    Completed: 1        NaN              NaN          NaN
6           Community   Resident Name       Date  Document Status  Last Update
7     Station Kingdom   Pretty Woman   9/12/2023      Not Started          NaN
8         My Goodness        Ugly Man  7/21/2023        Completed    7/26/2023
9           Community   Resident Name       Date              NaN          NaN
10  Station Kingdom1   Pretty Woman2   8/22/2023              NaN          NaN
11      My Goodness1        Ugly Man1   4/8/2023              NaN          NaN
12          Landmark2       Nice Guys  9/12/2023              NaN          NaN
13   Iceland Kingdom2    Mr. Heroshi2  7/14/2023              NaN          NaN
14     More Kingdom 2      King Kong   8/31/2023              NaN          NaN
```

How do I modify current code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100877/how-to-select-certain-columns-and-rows-based-on-keyword-in-column1) question was a **moving target**, and I don't exclude the possibility that this one might be as well. The old [regex](https://regex101.com/r/gtyt3b/2) pattern failed on your new csv simply because the format of the dataset is now different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77100877/1) one (*for which the pattern was made at first*).

Now, you can try this :

```
 pat = r"(\w+),+$\n[^,]+.+?\n,+\n(.+?)(?=\n,{2,})" # to update in `read_block`

 df = read_block(names=["Admissions", "Readmissions"], igidx=False)
```

> Demo : [[*regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/nsjFZ0/2)]
>
> *Scroll down because I used an exact copy of the given [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrhkc.png)/csv*

Output :

```
print(df)

                                  Community ResidentName         Date DocumentStatus Last Update Resident Name
Admissions   0                 Test Station     Jane Doe    9/12/2023           Sent   9/12/2023           NaN
             1               Test Station 2     John Doe    9/12/2023    Not Started         NaN           NaN
             2  Alibaba Fizgerald Super Man    9/12/2023  Not Started            NaN         NaN           NaN
             3              Iceland Kingdom  Super Woman    9/12/2023   Not Started          NaN           NaN
Readmissions 0              Station Kingdom          NaN    9/12/2023    Not Started         NaN  Pretty Woman
             1                  My Goodness          NaN    7/21/2023      Completed  7/26/2023       Ugly Man
```

> *I would like to have a separate output using a keyword ("Admissions", "Readmissions") in the 1st column as a variable in the code.*

Then use `df.droplevel(1).reset_index(names="block")`.

Comment: How/where do I apply the  df.droplevel(1).reset_index(names="block") ?

Comment: You can apply it like this : `df = read_block(names=["Admissions", "Readmissions"], igidx=False).droplevel(1).reset_index(names="block")`.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great stuff. I should learn how to be better in Python expression.

Comment: Question. What is purpose of "block"? If I put "Admissions" or "Readmissions", it appears that I get same output.

Comment: If you mean `names=block`, this one will just rename the first column. Without it, you get a column named `index`. Check [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Comment: I am having a difficulty with putting dataframe object inside the code that starts with  "  with open("Test1.csv") as f:  "  How do I replace "Test1.csv" with data frame object? I might create a new post using the code you provided soon.

Comment: This is my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449311/python-how-to-insert-result-of-data-frame-inside-with-open-statement

Comment: Can you please take a look at this new post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449311/python-how-to-insert-result-of-data-frame-into-read-block-function) and let me know why "No object to concat" error occurs?  It also occurs when I test in a local drive. If I drop "with open("Test1.csv") as f:", would it work?